How to create a new folder in the VS Code on the Ubuntu while opening one
Is there any way to create a new folder in the VS Code on Ubuntu with some shortcut in the menu that pops up after one presses ctrl + k + o (open folder)? Ik that it can be done on Windows with just ctrl + shift + N, but this shortcut doesn't work for me on Ubuntu in this menu
I tried ctrl + shift + N (as on Windows) but it didn't worked for me

you could open an issue ticket asking to have this feature. if you do, please add a link here to it. also, I'm on the fence about whether this question is on-topic for SO, since the file explorer dialog this question is about is technically part of the windowing system,... but I'm not leaning to "off-topic" since I have a feeling this is something that VS Code could implement and has control over as the invoker of the windowing system.
